# Speed of Voyager 1

Tags: speed, rocket-science, solar-system, space-travel, solar-system-exploration

I was reading Wikipedia which stated

> ....Voyager 1's current relative velocity is 17.062  km/s, or 61,452 kilometres per hour (38,185 mph).....

It travels away from sun. So sun's gravity must slow it down. What propels Voyager to that speed?

Comment: Voyager 1 is here:
https://www.live-counter.com/where-is-voyager-1/ Every second 17 km!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rocket fuels initially, followed by a series of gravitational assists (slingshots):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist
The linked article mentions Voyager 1 mission as an example.

Answer (score 5):

Gravitational force decreases with distance squared. So the deceleration due to the sun is negligible at that distance.

Acceleration due to gravity is given by $\frac{GM}{r^2}$, where $G$ is the gravitational constant $6.67\times 10^{-11} \mathrm{m}^3 \mathrm{kg}^{-1} \mathrm{s}^{-2}$. The mass of sun is $2\times 10^{30} \mathrm{kg}$ and the distance is $2\times 10^{13} \mathrm{m}$.

Plugging those values in gives a slowing down of $3 \times10^{-7} \mathrm{m} \mathrm{s}^{-2}$, or losing $300$ nanometers per second every second.

Answer (score -3):

i guess some other body in the space is pulling it towards itself and because it has been travelling since very long time, it could have achieved that acceleration. it's just a hypothesis of mine